# Archive fails for list items with inactive user(Those are disabled in AD )

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, records-center, archive

I have a list with "*Information Management Policy*" enabled in it, list contains few people picker columns and it has few user's who are no more in the company and so their profile are disabled in the AD. These kind of list items are moved to record center "*Drop off library*" but from the *drop off library*, it doesn't moves to the destination list, because of the inactive users in the list items.

In ULS we get the following errors,

> Metadata contained a user field which could not be resolved. User does
>   not exist or is not unique

Now we have more than 2000 items orphaned in the "Drop Off library", how to handle this case.?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to remove that person/group field from the content type in the drop off library/destination library?

If that isn't possible, you might need a workflow/timer job/event receiver/PowerShell process to check the drop off folder and check for disabled users and replace it with a service type account or a generic user account like NoLonger WorksHere.

This is the same type of practice employed by migration tools, allowing you to replace deactivated AD accounts with someone else. I think you'd need to do the same type of thing here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please tell me, in which tool this approach is followed.?

Comment: I've seen it personally in both Metalogix and Sharegate tools, allowing you to map users that cannot be found to another user account when migrating content around> I presume Avepoint and other tools do this and would be easy to check for in any custom thing you may write.